# Get Error in WebGL: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have Unity project created in Unity 5.2.3. I open this project in Unity 5.3.3p3 and compile for WebGl and get error: Invoking error handler due to
ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: Do you create a blank project or it is project downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: I made project in Unity 5.2.3. I build project for WebGL and get error

Comment: Event I get error if compile in Unity 5.3.3

Comment: In mozilla in console : http://prntscr.com/amogyf

Answer (score 0):

I find answer: in my code was line: Application.ExternalCall("$('#ViewerBox').data('unityViewer')." + method, values);

With symbol $

Comment: It is probably jQuery reference, so if you add jQuery to your html it should  fix the problem